# Converting JSON to Java Object in RESTful app

Tags: java, json, rest, jsf, resteasy

I have a rest service with the following methods:

```
@GET
@Path("/{param}/timings/{param2}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TimingModel> getTimings(@PathParam("param") int param, @PathParam("param2") int param2) {
    //return some list
}
```

And I have the two following methods to consume the service

```
public List<TimingClient> getTimings() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("some_url");
    Response response = target.request().get();
    List<TimingClient> readEntity = response.readEntity(ArrayList.class);
    return readEntity;
}
```

Now the problem is that I cannot cast back to my data model (Timing Client), and I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to models.TimingClient
```

Although if I access this method from a JSF page, I get the list perfectly.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.timings}">
```

How can I cast back to a Java Object?

Environment:

- RestEasy
- Wildfly 10.0
- JSF Mojarra 2.2

Comment: You can use the same `GenericType` argument in the `readEntity` call if you need the `Response` for something else.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks, it worked!